Fitting function to compton continuum of data measured by scintillator detector
I have measured the spectrum of $ \:^{60}$Co with an NaI-scintillator detector. Now I want to fit a function to the measured compton continuum. My idea was, that the measured counts are proportional to the Klein-Nishina cross section, so I tried to fit a function proportional to that to the data. That didn't really work tho. Is my idea right, or am I wrong? In the figure the channelnumber is linear with the energy of the incident photon.
Edit: Actually I need to find the area under the backscattering peaks to calculate the peak-to-total-ratio. My idea was to substract the Compton-continuum to get there, but if there is no way to describe the continuum by a function, do you have an other idea to extract the backscattering peaks?

It's complicated. Some of the events are single Compton scattering, but some aren't. You have doubles, where the photon scatters twice in the detector. You have photons that scattered into the detector from material around it.
To really model such an experiment, you have to understand the full geometry of the apparatus: what materials are present and how they are arranged and illuminated.

Do you have an idea how I could still extract the backscattering peaks from the data?
